# Chrome: Ignore certain hacked passwords?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome informs you about hacked passwords, i.e. your passwords found in data breaches.

Since I have a bunch of default credentials (admin/admin etc.) on VM development environments, I constantly get those warnings - so much so that I can no longer detect actual security breaches. How can I ignore certain URLs or passwords?